# Selecting NULL values in Android SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm executing the following method with no success beacause of the selectArgs being incorrect (at least this is what I believe.

**findAll:**

```
public Collection<Object> findAllByCodigoSetorOrderByStatusWhereDataAgendamentoIsNull(Integer vendedor) {
    Collection<Object> objects = null;
    String selection = Object.FIELDS[20] + "=?" + " OR " + Object.FIELDS[20] + "=?" + " OR " + Object.FIELDS[20] + "=?" + " AND " + Object.FIELDS[6] + "=?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { "''", "'null'", "NULL", String.valueOf(vendedor) };
    Collection<ContentValues> results = findAllObjects(Object.TABLE_NAME, selection, selectionArgs, Object.FIELDS, null, null, Object.FIELDS[4]);
    objects = new ArrayList<Object>();
    for (ContentValues result : results) {
        objects.add(new Object(result));
    }
    return objects;
}
```

**findAllObjects:**

```
protected Collection<ContentValues> findAllObjects(String table, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String[] columns, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        ContentValues contentValue = null;
        Collection<ContentValues> contentValues = null;
        try {
            db = openRead(this.helper);
            if (db != null) {
                cursor = db.query(table, columns, selection, selectionArgs, groupBy, having, orderBy);
                contentValues = new ArrayList<ContentValues>();
                for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {
                    cursor.moveToPosition(i);
                    contentValue = new ContentValues();
                    for (int c = 0; c < cursor.getColumnCount(); c++) {
                        contentValue.put(cursor.getColumnName(c), cursor.getString(c));
                    }
                    contentValues.add(contentValue);
                    cursor.moveToNext();
                }
            }
            return contentValues;
        } finally {
            close(db);
        }
    }
```

How can I correctly select and compare a column to - null, 'null' and '' using the db.query?

Comment: Are you handling your data with a `Cursor`?

Comment: Edited to make que question clearer... thanks for the question Cornholio.

Comment: The easiest way to just check a row for a null value is this -
`if (cursor.isNull(cursor.getColumnIndex("my_column")) doStuff();`. Is there any reason you can't use that?

Comment: 1 - The findAllObjects is generic... I would have to create a whole new method to manipulate the cursor.
2 - The reading speed would get extremely downsized.

Comment: I hear your concerns - what are you checking the value for? Do you want to exclude those rows with null values there, or do you want to do something else with them?

Comment: Return and list them in a grid to a Web GUI (jQuery-ui).

Comment: In that case, wouldn't it be easier to make the null check part of your query? i.e., `SELECT blah FROM blah WHERE blah IS NULL;`

Comment: COULD be... but what will be the point of using the selectionArgs then? That's my concern. If it's the only option... ok.

Comment: You cannot use NULL as an argument value bind. SQL is fun!

Comment: Nice! not even 'null' ? Maybe that's the problem then. Post your answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Android's database API does not allow to pass `NULL` values as parameters; it allows only strings.
(This is a horrible design bug. Even worse, [SQLiteStatement](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteStatement.html) *does* allow all types for parameters, but works only for queries that return a single value.)

You have no choice but to change the query string to `blah IS NULL`.

Comment: This should (I hope already is) marked as a bug/request on Android lists.

Comment: The `is null` necessity is traditional SQL syntax. `= null` doesn't return results in _any_ SQL database management system. And it also doesn't make sense to use an argument for it. First of all because the syntax is different and secondly because you always use the same string anyway. In your case I would use argument substitution *only for the variable vendedor*. For those other - fixed - values it's simply not needed and thus a waste of CPU cycles and battery life (even if only slightly). They are useful only if the arguments can contain variable values as for your last argument.

Comment: @CL. Indeed, SQLiteStatement is a horrible class. Borders on uselessness.

Comment: This answer and discussion helped me today. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Old question but i was still stuck on this for a few hours until i found this answer. For whatever reason this strange behaviour (or bug) still exists within the android sdk, if you want to query against null values simply do

```
SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

contentValues.put("columnName", newValue);

String nullSelection = "columnName" + " IS NULL";

db.update("tableName", contentValues, nullSelection, null);
db.close();
```

In this example i am updating values, but it is a similar concept when just selecting values

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other answers, for null "IS NULL" need to be used. Here is some convenience code for having both null and strings (I'm using delete in the example but the same can be done for other methods, e.g. query):

```
public void deleteSomething(String param1, String param2, String param3) {
    ArrayList<String> queryParams = new ArrayList<>();

    mDb.delete(TABLE_NAME,
            COLUMN_A + getNullSafeComparison(param1, queryParams) + "AND " +
                    COLUMN_B + getNullSafeComparison(param2, queryParams) + "AND " +
                    COLUMN_C + getNullSafeComparison(param3, queryParams),
            queryParams.toArray(new String[0]));
}

private String getNullSafeComparison(String param, List<String> queryParams) {
    if (param == null) {
        return " IS NULL ";
    } else {
        queryParams.add(param);
        return " = ? ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind **NULL** values to *SQLiteStatement*:

```
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    SQLiteStatement stmt = db.compileStatement("UPDATE table SET " +
            "parameter=? WHERE id=?");
    if (param == null)
        stmt.bindNull(1);
    else
        stmt.bindString(1, param);
    stmt.execute();
    stmt.close();
    db.close();
```

Comment: `SQLiteStatement` can only be called if the result set is 1 column x 1 line ([see doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteStatement.html))