# Filter database and show results where 2 conditions are met

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-sqlite

I'm trying to filter my sqlite database to show only results where more than one condition are met.

```
override fun onCreateLoader(p0: Int, p1: Bundle?): Loader<Cursor> {
    val projection = arrayOf(
            WalletEntry._ID,
            WalletEntry.KEY_TITLE,
            WalletEntry.KEY_LAST_DATE,
            WalletEntry.KEY_TRANSACTION_PLACE,
            WalletEntry.KEY_LAST_EXPENSE_VALUE,
            WalletEntry.KEY_LAST_TRANSACTION_TITLE,
            WalletEntry.KEY_VALUE_AFTER,
            WalletEntry.KEY_LOCALES,
            WalletEntry.KEY_CURRENCY
    )

    val data = "string" // specified result

    val selection = "${WalletEntry.KEY_TITLE} = ?" // AND WalletEntry.KEY_TRANSACTION_PLACE IS NOT NULL
    val selectionArgs = arrayOf(data)

    return applicationContext?.let { context ->
        CursorLoader(context,
                WalletEntry.CONTENT_URI,
                projection,
                selection,
                selectionArgs,
                null)
    }!!
}
```

What I mean, in provided code where I initialize selection I want to choose rows where title equals variable `data` and column `KEY_TRANSACTION_PLACE` is not null.

So, how should I correct my selection/selectionArgs to filter those results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it:

```
val selection = "${WalletEntry.KEY_TITLE} = ? AND ${WalletEntry.KEY_TRANSACTION_PLACE} IS NOT NULL"
```

Answer (score 0):

As answered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15954695/3621353) answer, the database API does not allow to pass NULL values as parameters. Only strings are allowed. So I prefer to use simple SQL query here. Or you can use the new [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room) persistence library if your app uses really complicated database.